# PHP file are downloaded instead of executing when redirected from an html

Tags: php, html, web

I have an homepage.html source code that links to a login.php, when i go to the php file through the html instead of showing the page it downloads it, but when i open the file by typing localhost/login.php it works perfectly fine. I'm new into php and html and i don't know what to do.

I want my php displayed in the web instead of download the file, i'm new into programming php and html and i don't know how to fix it, please if anybody can tell me a step by step on how to fix it, thank you..

Comment: Do you open homepage.html in you browser as file from your disk or via localhost/homepage.html?

Comment: Can you add the `a` tag that links to login page from home page?

Comment: Consider including the applicable HTML / PHP code with your question.